# Why do I receive an error when initializing a record with an option?

Tags: f#, assembly-binding-redirect

Why do I receive an error when initializing a record with an option?

**The following line fails my unit test:**

```
let name =      { First=String20("Scott"); Last=String20("Nimrod"); Suffix=None }
```

**Test Result:**

> Result StackTrace:    at CreateModuleViewModel.Tests.submit module()
>   Result Message:   System.MissingMethodException : Method not found:
>   'Void Name..ctor(String20, String20,
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1)'.

**The test is as follows:**

```
module CreateModuleViewModel.Tests

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework
open UILogic.State
open CreateModule.UILogic
open ManageModule.Entities

[<Test>]
let ``submit module`` () =

    // Setup
    let viewModel = CreationViewModel()

    let name =      { First=String20("Scott"); Last=String20("Nimrod"); Suffix=None }

    let duration =  { Hours=1; Minutes=30; Seconds=0 }
    let moduleItem = { Author=name; Duration=duration }

    // Tets
    viewModel.Add(moduleItem)

    // Verify
    viewModel.Modules.Head = moduleItem |> should equal true
```

**The record definition is as follows:**

```
type String20 = String20 of string

type Name = { 
    First:String20
    Last:String20
    Suffix:String20 option 
}
```

**Why am I receiving this error?**

Comment: Are the tests and the type definition in different assemblies?  If so, are you sure the correct version of the dll that provides the type definition is being called at runtime?  I don't see a code-related reason for you to experience this error.

Comment: definitely wrong versions of assemblies somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. My Test project is set to F# 3.1 and is locked to that version while all my other libraries are F# 4.0.

Comment: Scott, delete the reference to FSharp.Core from the test project, delete FSharp.Core from the packages.config file and then re-add the correct version of FSharp.Core from the list of assemblies, it'll be found under extensions.

Comment: Thanks TheInnerLight. I am fighting all these NuGet dependencies now for my test project. All my tests are failing and I am still trying to make all my projects happy. I followed your instructions and observed the version of my Test project's FSharp.Core is set to "True" within my properties window. Hence, all my other projects have the version set to "4.0". I'm now trying to figure out FsUnit: Unable to find a version of 'FSharp.Core' that is compatible with 'FsUnit 1.4.1 constraint: FSharp.Core (≥ 3.1.2.5)'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common cause for the `MissingMethodException` is that some of your dependencies is compiled against a different version of `FSharp.Core.dll` than the unit test library.

The way to solve this is to add `bindingRedirect` to your `app.config`. I think most unit test runners will respect the binding redirect too, and so this should fix the problem.

Mark Seemann [has a blog post about this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/30/how-to-use-fsharpcore-430-when-all-you-have-is-431/). Stealing his example, you need something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core"
                          publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.99.99.99"
                         newVersion="4.3.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The `newVersion` will be either `4.3.1.0` (Visual Studio 2013) or `4.4.0.0` (Visual Studio 2015). I changed the `oldVersion` here to a range that should include all versions that may be around.

The reason why this causes `MethodMissingException` is a bit subtle - but without the redirect, the runtime things that e.g. `option<T>` from one F# Core is not the same thing as `option<T>` from another version of F# Core and so it cannot find method that it was expecting.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. My test now passes. However, all my other previously passing tests now fail with the same error message. I am researching the blog provided but haven't yet identified the required app configuration resolve all dll conflicts.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated new version property of BindingRedirect from newVersion="4.3.1.0"  to: newVersion="4.4.0.0". I also followed TheInnerLight's advice and updated my FSharp.Core dll on my test project to point to FSharp4.0.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your configuration looks like. Are the other tests in the same project?

Comment: It's resolved now. Please reference my previous comment above. Thx again.